# Function expressions not updating values, functions beeing called only once (module)

Tags: javascript, function, module, expression

So basicly this.acceleration doesn't get updated whatever I do. I need a way to make a function update its values, so when they get changed from another function, it still works correctly. Here is what I mean:

```
function PropellingNozzle(power) {

    this.power = power;
    this.afterburner = "off";

    function acceleration (afterburner, power) {

        this.afterburner = afterburner;
            console.log(this.power);
        if(this.afterburner == "on") {
            this.acceleration = this.power*2;
        } 
        else if(this.afterburner == "off") {
            this.acceleration = this.power;
        }
            console.log("called");
            return this.acceleration
    }


    return {

        power: this.power,
        afterburner: this.afterburner,
        switchAfterburner: function() {
            if(this.afterburner == "off") {
                    this.afterburner = "on";
                }

                else if(this.afterburner == "on") {
                    this.afterburner = "off";
                }
        },
        acceleration: acceleration(this.afterburner, this.power)
    };
}
```

As you can see, I know started parsing the values and what no, just experimenting and it still does not work. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7utL5/) is the whole code part with the tests in jsfiddle. Preferebly, switchAfterburner should also be in PropellingNozzle function, but if it cannot work there is no problem for it to remain in the return. My task is to write the code as object oriented as possible with my knowledge so far

Comment: This part of your fiddle doesn't make sense `var nozzle = new propulsionUnits.PropellingNozzle(20);`. `propulsionUnits` refers to an object, not a constructor function.

Comment: propulsionUnits is my so called module. propulsionUnits.PropellinNozzle should refer to function PropellingNozzle which is indeed a constructor function. This part is already tested and works fine, if you could help me with my problem I will apreciate it

Comment: You should not return an object if you want to use the function as a constructor with `new` (not the source of your issue, but confusing).

Comment: Can you then suggest a fix for this? I want to group my constructors in this module...Maybe just get rid of the new, but then will it do the same job?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ma3s/1/) is another try I did. As you can see, the value doesn't get updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *are* calling it only once - when assigning the value to the `acceleration` property. You're not assigning the function expression to get re-evaluated whenever one of the values changes, but you're assigning its result value.

So what to do against this? You can

- update the `acceleration` property whenever one of the values it depends on changes. When they're only set by your functions (like `switchAfterBurner`) and not directly assigned from outside, it's easy to put the re-computation within those setters.
- use a getter method for the acceleration. Instead of just reading a property, the outside will call a `getAcceleration()` function which dynamically computes the correct value.

---

Btw, please use either

```
function PropellingNozzle(power) {
    this.power = power;
    this.afterburner = "off";
    this.switchAfterburner =  function() {…};
    …
}
var example = new PropellingNozzle(…);
```

or

```
function makePropellingNozzle(power) {
    …
    return {
        power: power,
        afterburner: "off",
        switchAfterburner: function() {…},
        …
    };
}
var example = makePropellingNozzle(…);
```

but not a mixture of both.